# FX Task, returning a value always returns null

Tags: java, javafx, task

I am trying to return a String from a FX Task.

Expected output: true,testABC.

Real output: true,null.

The call to the task:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Future<String> my_String = (Future<String>) pool.submit(new my_task());

    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println(my_String.isDone());
        System.out.println(my_String.get());//gettings the String from the future
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Return_test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }}
```

The task:

```
public class my_task extends Task<String>{

@Override
protected String call() throws Exception {
    String tempString = "testABC";
    return tempString;
}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) implements `Runnable`, but not `Callable`. So when you call `pool.submit(myTask)`, you are calling the [overloaded form of `ExecutorService.submit(...)` taking a `Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-). In general, of course, `Runnable`s do not return values, so the `Future` that is returned from that version of `submit(...)`, as Aerus has already pointed out, just returns `null` from its `get()` method (it cannot get a value from the `Runnable`).

However, `Task` also extends `FutureTask` directly, so you can use your task directly to get the result. Just do

```
Task<String> myTask = new my_task(); // Please use standard naming conventions, i.e. new MyTask();
pool.submit(myTask);

try {
    // sleep is unnecessary, get() will block until ready anyway
    System.out.println(myTask.get());
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Return_test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works very nice. I knew it would be possible to retrieve the value because of the FutureTask. Yet i still do not understand why i had to call get() on the task and not on the future?

Comment: Updated with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

From the `submit` Javadoc:

> The Future's `get` method will return `null` upon **successful** completion.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html : get()
Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Comment: Yes, the result being `null` as per the Javadoc snippet above.

Comment: Note which overloaded version of `submit(...)` you are calling: a `Task` is a `Runnable`, but not a `Callable`, so the `submit(...)` method just treats your task as a `Runnable` and calls its `run()` method. It can't get a result from that, since `run()` is `void`.